# Imap local cache server

Tags: imap, architecture

I'am not sure if it's the good place to ask the question. I would like to know if it's possible to have a local Imap cache server. The main IMAP server is by the provider. To improve performance I want to install an Imap on the LAN. When a user retrieves his emails, he takes them from the server on the LAN. I have seen that Perdition is a proxy imap, but I think it can't store email locally. Does anyone know if a such architecture exists ? Florent

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an usual IMAP-server like `dovecot` and fill it with messages fetched from the main server by `fetchmail` utility. If the main server is under your control and is also powered by `dovecot` you can use handy `dovecot`'s tool `dsync` to syncronize both instances.